# SVN browsing error session_set/session_checkip in Tuleap

Tags: svn, tuleap

When trying to browse the SVN tree I get this error message:

```
import viewvc File "/usr/share/viewvc/lib/viewvc.py", line 71, in session.session_set() File "/usr/share/tuleap/src/www/../utils/session.py", line 81, in session_set if session_checkip(row['ip_addr'], os.environ['REMOTE_ADDR']): File "/usr/share/tuleap/src/www/../utils/session.py", line 33, in session_checkip re
```

My configuration includes a reverseproxy on the front and LDAP (active directory) authentication. I've got this issue on v8.7, 8.6

fyi: updated to v8.8 no changes.

Easily is something in configuration, but I can't find what, also I don't find error logs.

Comment: Is your `$sys_ldap_server` (tuleap ldap config) fully qualified with `ldap://...` ?

Comment: Yes, it is. ldap://<AD server IP>

Comment: Are you in IP v4 or IP v6 ?

Comment: Internal network over IPv4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved, the reverse proxy used ipV6 so it was passing **HTTP-X-FORWARDED-FOR** header with IPv6 address.

Function *session_checkip* works only with ipV4 addresses since check the class B subnet with a simple split string.

Changing the behavior of reverse proxy (disabling ipv6) solved this issue.